# In One cell Formula is working but not in Other

Tags: excel

I have pasted same formula in other cell. It is showing #value! Error.

=SUM(MP_Report!Z:Z,IF(MP_Report!K:K,"EPIC"))

I also tried control+shift+Enter in formula tab. It didnt work.

Please help me on this

Comment: `SUMIF` is normally preferable as per Joe's answer but for this sort of syntax you'd need it to be: =SUM(IF(MP_Report!K:K="EPIC",MP_Report!Z:Z)), confirmed with CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER .......but SUMIF is much more efficient...

Comment: @barryhoudini, Superb!!!! It worked out. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `=SUMIF(MP_Report!K:K,"EPIC",MP_Report!Z:Z)`